# Simple Java Client/Server Architecture - Which tools?

Tags: java, architecture, client

I'm working on my Bachelor's dissertation and I decided to develop a client / server application.
I already tried ActiveMQ but I'm not 100% sure if that is the right solution.

The thing I need is simply a server application which provide methods; these methods should be called by the client modules.

Both - client and server - has access to for example a GreetingService Interface:

```
public interface GreetingService {
  public String sayHello();
}
```

The implementation of the GreetingService is made on the server side. In the example above the sayHello()-Method could return the string "hello".

My client application should now call the sayHello()-Method from the interface and get the return value from the GreetingServiceImpl.

I hope my example was close enough. Which tools / framework / etc. can you suggest me?

Comment: This sounds like a textbook case for Java's RMI functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with the same kind of problems. There are many ways of dealing with this, the best and easiest way I can think of [java Remote Method Invocation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html) services.

Comment: Yes they are synchronous (see http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Ecommerce/jms/) However there are multiple mechanisms available that can turn them into asynchronous calls using FutureTasks (see http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/futuretask)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get a simple HelloWorld Java server is probably with Play Framework, see http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/firstapp for a very simple app walkthrough.

Comment: Is that for Java web applications only?